# Looping around in Enumeration in C#

Tags: c#, addition, enumeration, subtraction

Is there some way to automatically loopback when the value of an Enumeration reaches the end while adding or subtracting values.

E.g. When using DateTime.DayOfWeek it is defined as:

```
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

I have a function where I'm checking if a string array contains yesterday.

```
DateTime rn = DateTime.Now;
string[] daysOfWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Saturday"};
if (daysOfWeek.Contains((rn.DayOfWeek - 1).ToString()))
    ...
```

If today is Sunday. Is there some way to make the rn.DayOfWeek enumeration to loop back around the beginning to Saturday in this case?
Similarly if I'm adding instead of subtracting, can one somehow loop around the end from Saturday (6) back to Sunday (0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding/subtracting when dealing with enums. That is dangerous ground. Instead, you should be adding/subtracting days to your DateTime:

```
string today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
string tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
string yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, don't know how I missed that. I can just use `if (daysOfWeek.Contains((rn.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek.ToString()))`

Answer (score 1):

I guess in this particular case it could be

```
DateTime rn = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
string[] daysOfWeek = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Saturday" };
if (daysOfWeek.Contains(((rn.DayOfWeek) == 0 ? rn.DayOfWeek + 6 : rn.DayOfWeek - 1).ToString()))
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
```

Although I agree that such code generally should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an automatic "looping" behavior on random enumerations, however, there are some ways you could handle your problem.

Most of the time, you could simply use the [% operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx), which in the case of `DayOfWeek` would amount to something like this:

```cs
// Prints Friday
Console.WriteLine((DayOfWeek)(((int)DayOfWeek.Saturday + 6) % 7));
```

You could also write an extension method like this one:

```cs
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DayOfWeek AddDays(this DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int count)
    {
        if (dayOfWeek < 0 || (int)dayOfWeek > 6) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        int adjustedValue = ((int)dayOfWeek + count) % 7;

        return (DayOfWeek)(adjustedValue < 0 ? adjustedValue + 7 : adjustedValue);
    }
}
```

With this extension method, you could do something like this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(DayOfWeek.Sunday.AddDays(-1)); // Prints "Saturday"
Console.WriteLine(DayOfWeek.Sunday.AddDays(1)); // Prints "Monday"
Console.WriteLine(DayOfWeek.Sunday.AddDays(7)); // Prints "Sunday"
Console.WriteLine(DayOfWeek.Sunday.AddDays(-7)); // Prints "Sunday"
```

Comment: Yes, that looks good. So if `dow` is a `DayOfWeek`, one can get the preceding day of week with `var dowBefore = (DayOfWeek)((dow - 1 + 7) % 7);` where we have the `+7` to make sure no subresult is negative. Of course it is the same as `var dowBefore = (DayOfWeek)((dow + 6) % 7);` mathematically. Going backwards `1` day-of-week is the same as going forward `6` days-of-week.

Comment: Good point, instead of doing -1 to days of week, one can do +6 (7-1) and then modulus 7 to bring it back within range of 0 to 6. Thanks, this helped me fix another part of the code.

Comment: While this interesting I'm trying to see how your answer would fit the above use case when one is using DateTime.DayOfWeek enumeration. Can one overload the add or subtract operator for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a following extension method (can easily be changed for string arrays).

```
public static bool ContainsYesterday(this DayOfWeek[] days)
{
    return days.Contains(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek);
}
```

edited as previous version had a bug specified in comment.

Comment: Do you know how `%` operator works when its first operand is negative (which is possible because you subtract `1`)?

Comment: What if today is `0` (Sunday) and you want to test if yesterday was `6` (Saturday)? Do you maintain that `(-1) % 7 == 6`?

Comment: There is not much reason for the array since the `enum` can be cast to `int`. If you really want the array, don't use `ToArray()` since all it does in this case is copy a fresh and new array into yet another array instance. Use `static DayOfWeek[] allValues = (DayOfWeek[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to do this but if you're happy working with integers then it's pretty easy, you just want to remap all your values from -X to +X into the 0-6 range so for a positive value you'd do

value+1 (to remap to 1-7 range since we're going to divide by 7) %7 (this gives you the remainder of the division by 7, so 1%7 = 1 8 = 1 etc etc, you've got it looping every 7 days) -1 (to remap out 1-7 range to your 0-6 enum value) and cast that as your enum.

Now we just need to consider negative value and convert the negative value into something positive first before passing it into our previous function. In this case we want to map the oposite days (-1 is the same as +6, one day before the start of the week is 6 days after the end of the week etc), so if your value is negative you want to do abs(value) to make it positive and the substract it from 7 to remap it into the positive range

Here's some code (untested)

```
if(value < 0)
{
    value = 7 - Math.Abs(value)
}

value++; (remap 0-6 to 1-7)
value = value % 7; (remap 1 - int.maxvalue to 1-7)
value--; (remap 1-7 to 0-6;
```

And now value contains the number that maps to your enum.

Comment: I suggest you go for Grozz's answer which is more generic / less magic numbers

Comment: So technically you can use `value = (DayOfWeek)((int)++value % 7 - 1);` right?

Comment: @rboy Grozz's answer does not seem correct, and neither does the formula of your comment here. You saw my comment to GoldenCrystal's answer; there's a concise and correct formula.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen what you comments to GoldenCrystal is correct. However I also see Grozz's answer works fine and what code I posted above is also working. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @rboy Grozz has edited his answer. The version present when I wrote my comments was incorrect.